# How to retrieve the goal name in Analytics using APIs

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve the name of my Analytics goals through the Google API using PHP. I tried this code but I don't understand why it creates a loop and does not return any value to me.
Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks so much

```
  $goals = $analytics->management_goals->listManagementGoals('123456', 'UA-123456-1', '~all');

  foreach ($goals->getItems() as $key) {
      $html = <<<HTML
        <pre>
            Goal id              = {$key->getId()}
            Goal name            = {$key->getName()}
            HTML;
      $html .= '</pre>';
      print $html;
  }
```

Comment: Have you authenticated? are you using oauth or service account to access the api?

Comment: Yes, i'm authenticated and i use oauth account to access the api